# jqGrid edit custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem with data validation on an editable cell. I make some cells of one column editable based on the values of these cells. Here is the code of the grid:

```
jQuery("#cart").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    autowidth: true,
    height: tabHeight,
    gridview: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    autoencode: true,
    loadtext: "იტვირთება",
    multiselect: true,
    idPrefix:"b",
    colNames: ['დასახელება', 'რაოდენობა მინ.', 'რაოდენობა მაქს.', 'პოზიცია', 'რაოდენობა', 'ფასი'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'asktx',
        index: 'asktx',
        width: 40,
        sorttype: "string",
    },
    {
        name: 'menge_min',
        index: 'menge_min',
        width: 30,
        sorttype: "number",
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        name: 'menge_max',
        index: 'menge_max',
        width: 30,
        sorttype: "number",
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        name: 'srvpos',
        index: 'svrpos',
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        name: 'menge',
        index: 'menge',
        width: 30,
        sorttype: "number",
        editrules: {
            required: true, number: true, custom: true, custom_func: checkInterval
        },
        editable: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'price',
        index: 'price',
        width: 30,
        sorttype: "string",
        search: false,
    }],
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "არჩეული მომსახურებები",
    gridComplete: function () {
        var $this = $(this), ids = $this.jqGrid('getDataIDs'), i, l = ids.length;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(ids[i]);
            if (rowData.menge_min != rowData.menge_max && !rowData.menge) {
                menge_min = rowData.menge_min;
                menge_max = rowData.menge_max;
                $this.jqGrid('editRow', ids[i], true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am using `gridComplete` to check if values of two cells are equal and if they are not, I am making a column called `"menge"` editable in that row. I have also done the validation for constant values, like if I need to check whether this menge value is between a and b, I can do that and all is fine, although now I need to validate that field value based on the values of `"menge_min"` and `"menge_max"` field values, that are hidden. I see that custom function `"checkInterval"` can have only two parameters, so I can not pass the row ID there. Is there any way for getting some kind of information about the row which is currently being edited in custom validation function?

I fill the grid based on click event on another grid, here is the validation function for now:

```
var checkInterval = function (value, colname) {
            value = parseInt(value);
            mange_min = parseInt(menge_min);
            menge_max = parseInt(menge_max);

            if (value < menge_min || value > menge_max) {
                return [false, "რაოდენობა უნდა იყოს " + menge_min + "-" + menge_max + " ინტერვალში"];
            } else {
                return [true];
            }
        }
```

As for multiple editable rows, it is kind of requirement and the user knows he/she entered a correct value if there is no validation error popup and continue to edit other rows. The jqGrid version is 4.5.1.

here is the select event of the other grid:

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
    if (id && id !== lastSel) {
        jQuery(this).restoreRow(lastSel);
        lastSel = id;
        var celValue = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);
        var rowCount = $("#cart").getGridParam("reccount") + 1;
        if (celValue.menge_min == celValue.menge_max )
            celValue.menge = celValue.menge_min;
        var newID = id + rowCount;
        jQuery("#cart").jqGrid('addRowData', newID, celValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: You use `datatype: 'local'`, but specify no `data` parameter. How you fill the grid? You use `checkInterval` for custom validation, but you don't included the corresponding JavaScript code. Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Why you start editing *multiple rows*? It have many disadvantages. The user can not saves one row and start editing the another one without understanding that the other changes are still unsaved.

Comment: Correct filling of the grid allows to remove all hidden columns from the grid. One could access all properties of every item directly without the requirement to place the data in hidden column and get from DOM every time.

Comment: thanks for quick response, this is my first interaction with jqgrid, I am not sure that I have chosen all the best practices, so with that in mind, I will edit my post to provide answers for your questions as I should have included them in the question, my fault :)

Comment: It's no problem! I just try to help you, but I miss some information. I could help with with `custom_func`, but I need to know **how you fill the grid with data**  to give you any advises how the improve the code from `gridComplete`. I'll post some information in my answer.

Comment: I am appending data to this row on selected event on another jqgrid, I will add that code also, as it is too long for comment

Comment: მიესალმები, I posted some advices in my answer. I visited Tbilisi many years before during I was studied at the University Novosibirsk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that your problem is accessing to the content of `menge_max` in `menge_min` column inside of `custom_func` callback.

You current code set `menge_min` and `menge_max` to the values from **the last row of the grid**. The loop inside of `gridComplete` overwrite the value of the variables.

I would recommend you don't start editing mode for multiple rows. It generates many problems. For example the rows could be modified, but not saved. The sorting and filtering (searching) are blocked in the grid. One can use the possibility only after saving of changes in all rows. Typically one implement starting of editing on click on any cell of the grid. The user sees the starting of editing and he/she can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the data. Between editing the rows the user can sort or filter the grid (you can add call of `filterToolbar` method to create the filter bar). In the way the user can easy find the requested row of data and then edit the data.

The version 4.5.1, which you currently use, is very old. It was published about 3 years ago. You have no callbacks with exception `custom_func`, which you can use and because you edit *multiple rows* at the same time.

The simplest way to solve your problems would be updating to free jqGrid 4.13.0. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the fork of jqGrid which I develop starting with the end 2014. It have enchantment which you need. I implemented *alternative way* to specify custom validation. Instead of usage `custom: true, custom_func: checkInterval` one can use `custom: checkInterval` instead (`custom` property is not Boolean, but callback function instead). In the case the `custom` callback would get **one** parameter `options` with many properties which you can use. The properties are described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/92e128be0c830944053a29b7a69a31db13540d08) (see [the comment](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/pull/184#issuecomment-164195367) for additional information). You could need `options.rowid` and to use `var item = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", options.rowid);` to get **full item of data** where `item.menge_max` and `item.menge_min` can be used.

Additionally I would recommend you to use [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) inside of `onSelectRow` or parent grid. You can use `initdata` option to specify the data of the grid and no `rowID`. The documentation of `addRow` described the default value of `rowID` incorrectly. The default value of `rowID` is `null`, even for the version 4.5.1 (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.1/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L414) of code), and jqGrid *generates unique rowid automatically* in the case. You can then remove the code from `gridComplete`. If you would implement starting of inline editing on selection the rows in the grid then the user can do all what he need without any restrictions.

The last remark. If you would migrate to free jqGrid you can remove `menge_min`, `menge_max` and `svrpos` columns from the grid. Instead of that you can use `additionalProperties: ["menge_min", "menge_max", "svrpos"]`. It informs free jqGrid to *save* the value of the properties in the local data, but not place the information in some hidden cells of the grid (no unneeded information in the DOM of the page).

In any way you can remove unneeded `sorttype: "string"` and `index` properties from `colModel`.

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg, this answer is far more than what I was expecting to get while posting my question here. I have just migrated to Free jqGrid as you suggested and changed my custom function in a matter of minutes and everything is how I needed to be now! Also, thank you very much for other general recommendations and references, you have helped me a lot

Comment: @user3640553: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you. I implemented many new features in free jqGrid, which can essentially reduce the code and improves the look of the grid. If you just migrate to free jqGrid I'd recommend you to use [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) instead of jQuery UI icons. You need just add the CSS `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">` and to add `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option to your grid.

Comment: @user3640553: Another feature: you can use Bootstrap CSS *instead of* jQuery UI CSS. You can add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">` and `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">` and then to use the option `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` or `guiStyle: "bootstrapPrimary"`. See some demos [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README.md#main-new-features-and-improvements-implemented-in-the-version-4130). Best wishes!